# How to get a DirectoryReader handle to my www directory in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, filesystems, directory

Is there a way to get a handle to the directory in which my index.html is hosted?

I need to get a file from my www directory in a **universal** fashion.

Thanks!

Comment: Which platform? What do you need to do with the file? All files should be readily available via JavaScript and HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The www directory is part of the app bundle so is read only - that means there is no need to list the files at run time.

Whatever list you need can be included at compile time, and you can then use ajax to access the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the www directory is not part of the file system so you cannot use a DirectoryReader to get the list of files.